# Linux 64bit calling convention uses register to pass 'this' pointer, but code is less efficient?

Tags: c++, linux, performance, gcc, 64-bit

> My question

From wikipedia 64 bit API calling convention uses registers to pass first parameters in rdi, rsi, etc.

But I found: 64 bit, when calling class's member function(e.g. constructor), the code generated by compiler will move "this" pointer from register to memory, and function call will use this memory.

So I felt:  the usage of register (as a mediator) is redundant.

> Experiment

Observe the constructor generated by gcc and check disassembly via gdb.
First 32bit.

```
struct Test
{
  int i;
  Test(){
    i=23;
  }
};
int main()
{
  Test obj1;
  return 0;
}

$ gcc Test.cpp -g -o Test -m32
```

gdb to start it, break at 'i=23', check the disassembly:

```
(gdb) disassemble
Dump of assembler code for function Test::Test():
   0x08048484 <+0>: push   %ebp
   0x08048485 <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
=> 0x08048487 <+3>: mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax #'this' pointer in%ebp+8, passed by caller
   0x0804848a <+6>: movl   $0x17,(%eax)   #Put "23" at the first member location
   0x08048490 <+12>:    nop
   0x08048491 <+13>:    pop    %ebp
   0x08048492 <+14>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

> Question(1)

This 32 bit version seems efficient.But，'this' pointer is not passed by 'ecx' register like VC does. Does gcc use 'ecx' to store 'this' pointer?

---

Then 64bit:

```
(gdb) disassemble
Dump of assembler code for function Test::Test():
   0x0000000000400584 <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x0000000000400585 <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000000400588 <+4>: mov    %rdi,-0x8(%rbp) #rdi to store/ restore 'this'
=> 0x000000000040058c <+8>: mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax #Same as 32 bit version.
   0x0000000000400590 <+12>:    movl   $0x17,(%rax)
   0x0000000000400596 <+18>:    nop
   0x0000000000400597 <+19>:    pop    %rbp
   0x0000000000400598 <+20>:    retq   
End of assembler dump.
```

> Question(2)

This time, more instructions, the move of 'this' pointer from %rdi to memory seems to indicate，the register usage is useless, because finnaly it should be inside memory to be function parameter.

(2.1)For 64 bit, the first 2 parameters of function call are stored in rdi,rsi. But here seems no need for rdi to store 'this' pointer and restore it into memory again. We could 'push' this pointer directly and constructor could use it.

(2.2)And 64bit program requires an extra word size_t (%rbp-8) on stack to restore 'this' pointer.

So in all, the space and time efficiency of 64bit version are both worth than 32 bit. Is this due to 64bit calling convention, or just because I'm not telling gcc to optimize the code to the last bit of its strength?

When is 64bit faster?

Appreciate your suggestions. Thanks very much.

Comment: This kind consideration about instruction-level performance is pointless if you do not enable optimization. You might want to enable optimization (`-O`) and start your comparison again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in fact, the optimizer erases all of your code

even changing main to return obj1.i the code of Test::Test() is optimized to null:

```
0000000000400470 <main>:
  400470:   b8 17 00 00 00          mov    $0x17,%eax
  400475:   c3                      retq
```